# LASSO: Why we have to center the dependent variable

Tags: lasso, regularization

I'm trying to get into the topic of shrinkage models. I don't unterstand why it is important to center y. The consequence is, that we can ommit the intercept. But why I should care if the model contains an intercept or not. As the intercept is unpenalized, why I don't should run the lasso with uncentered y and an intercept ?

I hope, that someone can help me to get the right intuition

Comment: I think you are right that it doesn't matter. Since the intercept is unpenalized, you can center or not $y$ as you wish.

Comment: It's a convenience.  If you center everything, the intercept estimate is zero, so it's just one less thing the algorithm needs to worry about.

Comment: So it doesnt has a deeper intuition ?

Comment: I don't think so.  The deepest you can get here is the short calculus exercise that shows the intercept is always zero when everything is centered.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you enable intercept in most of the Lasso algorithms, what these algorithms do at backend is simply centering both X and y before regression. So if you enable intercept, you do not need to center y yourself.